# Is there any evidence that Harry grew to like using Sectumsempra?

Tags: harry-potter, dark-arts

I am asking this question based on Harry's actions in the 6th book and beyond.

His first target was Malfoy, he saw devastating effects that this spell can cause. At that point, the book led me to believe that Harry could've as well sworn to never use that spell again.

However, he used it on Inferi, and tried to use it on Snape. I can't recall if there were any other instances of Harry using it.

Which led me to believe that Harry came to like this spell somewhat. Maybe not for everyday use, more of a dark horse to keep in a pocket if the need ever rises.

Harry's signature was Expelliarmus, so I am curious if my assumption was correct: **Did Harry ever hold high regard to Sectumsempra as any sort of trump card? (Partially to avoid using Unforgivables)**

I'm asking because this is what I was led to believe after finishing the books. I simply want to know whether this is likely to be right or wrong. (I like unraveling psychology of characters from books.)

Comment: I don't think this is provable one way or the other, thus my close vote as primarily opinion based. As it is the most damaging spell we've ever seen Harry cast, it makes sense he would try it against the undead (because how would Avada Kedavra re-kill something? Better to try and rip them to shreds). As for trying it on Snape - the book does say that at the moment Harry cast it against Snape, Harry hated Snape as much as he hated Voldemort.

Comment: @NKCampbell While I believe that Harry was trying to use the most destructive spells in his arsenal to rid of infernals as fast as possible, there were many other ways to harm Snape beyond recognition, if Harry ever desired so. But he resorted to mentioned spell instead.

Comment: @NKCampbell Harry used Crucio on Bellatrix because of his hatred of that she did to Sirius. Crucio could've easily get his objective to make Snape hurt as much as possible out of hatred, but Harry seemed to swear to himself to never use this spell again. Harry faced same scenarios in book 5 and 6, where he hated 2 people to the point to hurt them. Nevertheless, he found Crucio to be repelling to ever use again. Not so much for the spell in question.

Comment: We don't know that he found Crucio too repelling to use again - that's speculation. There simply isn't enough information given in the text(s) to indicate why he chose Sectumsempra (and attempted Levicorpus but failed to cast it) - the out of universe answer is the simplest - Harry needed to attempt the HBP spells against Snape so Snape could reveal himself as the HBP. Anything else is purely speculation

Comment: You know, the thing about being an impulsive youth is that you end up saying the first thing that comes into your mind. Harry cast the _Sectumsempra_ spell because it was the first 'bad' spell he could think of that wouldn't immediately kill the opponent.

Comment: The other part of this is that out-of-universe, JKR needed a way to reveal the identity of the 'Half-blood Prince'.

Comment: In regards to Snape, Harry tried *five* different spells before falling back to Sectumsempra. He had gone through his entire repertoire of offensive spells and fell all the way back to **Levicorpus**. If he "liked" the spell he would have used it well before he ran out.

Comment: @KevinFee Yeah, I forgot that part. Nevertheless, it did help me understand Harry's character better from psychological PoV. However, it looks like such debates are very short-lived in child books =P

Comment: @VadzimSavenok I would like also note that two of those spell attempts against Snape *were* Crucio, but Snape said, "No Unforgivable Curses from you, Potter! You haven't got the nerve or the ability ---". So he hadn't sworn off that curse, either.

Comment: @KevinFee Yeah, it looks like I have exhausted everything possible out of the topic. It's safe to close the question now.

Comment: This question should be reopened - I have an answer based on what we see of Harry's opinion on using spells that do harm throughout the series.

Comment: This has a canon answer and should not be closed as primarily opinion based.

Comment: Wow, talk about raising a polar topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Knowing his character, it's likely he didn't grow to 'like' it.

Although occasionally Harry has attempted to use "worse" spells, Harry's general style of dueling and fighting tends to be nonlethal and causing minimal harm like Stupefy or Expelliarmus, including against opponents like Death Eaters and the Dark Lord himself. Even at the height of the wizarding war, when Harry understands how serious the situation is and is at his most mature during the series, he still largely avoided using any spells that actually cause harm.

> “Hagrid swerved, but the Death Eaters were keeping up with the bike; more curses shot after them, and Harry had to sink low into the sidecar to avoid them. Wriggling round, he cried, ‘Stupefy!’ and a red bolt of light shot from his own wand, cleaving a gap between the four pursuing Death Eaters as they scattered to avoid it.” <sub><sup>- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 4 (The Seven Potters)</sup></sub>

Expelliarmus is considered Harry's signature spell since he often uses it in battle, so much so that Lupin warns him, and he's discovered by the Death Eaters when he used it despite that warning.

> “I saw Stan Shunpike … you know, the bloke who was the conductor on the Knight Bus? And I tried to Disarm him instead of – well, he doesn’t know what he’s doing, does he? He must be Imperiused!’
>
> Lupin looked aghast.
> ‘Harry, the time for Disarming is past! These people are trying to capture and kill you! At least Stun if you aren’t prepared to kill!” <sub><sup>- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 5 (Fallen Warrior)</sup></sub>

Lupin is shocked at Harry's insistence on using nonharmful spells.

> “Yes, Harry,’ said Lupin with painful restraint, ‘and a great number of Death Eaters witnessed that happening! Forgive me, but it was a very unusual move then, under imminent threat of death. Repeating it tonight in front of Death Eaters who either witnessed or heard about the first occasion was close to suicidal!” <sub><sup>- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 5 (Fallen Warrior)</sup></sub>

However, Harry remains strongly morally opposed to using harmful spells, as says so when Lupin suggests the time for them is past.

> “I won’t blast people out of my way just because they’re there,’ said Harry. ‘That’s Voldemort’s job.” <sub><sup>- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 5 (Fallen Warrior)</sup></sub>

Each time he goes up against the Dark Lord, his go-to spell is Expelliarmus, which simply removes the opponent's wand from their hand.

#### After using it on Snape, that was the last time we saw him use it - though he used both Crucio and Imperio.

Once he finds out Snape invented Sectumsempra, Harry never attempted to use it again throughout the series. That may be because he associated it with Snape from then on, who he hated for killing Dumbledore.

**After the series, he may have used it out of necessity, but it's unlikely he'd ever grow to *like* it.**

It's entirely possible that, especially after his opinion of Snape changed, he may have used the spell out of necessity, like he did with Crucio and Imperio. However, he would almost certainly never grow to *like* it since he's shown a clear moral objection to any spell that does harm. In addition, Sectumsempra, when used against a person, can cause more lasting damage to them than either Crucio and Imperio, unless the specific countercurse is used. So, Harry might consider it worse to use Sectumsempra, especially as almost no one knows the countercurse.

Comment: He didn't strictly *need* to use Crucio. He used the Imperius Curse out of a clear necessity (coercing the goblin to go along with them robbing Gringott's), but he uses (or attempts to use) the Cruciatus Curse only in revenge (e.g. after Bellatrix killed Sirius Black).

Comment: You've got to mean it Harry. You know the spell. She killed him, she deserves it.

Comment: @EJS Well, *I* certainly don't think she deserved it! :P

Comment: You disagree with Voldemort? (At this point, the correct answer is "You dare to speak his name? You filthy half-blood!" or something to that effect :).)

Comment: @EJS You dare speak the Dark Lord's name?! You stand there... you dare... Filthy half-blood!!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure that we have to assume that he necessarily *liked* the spell.

The Inferi and the time that he tried to use it on Snape were unique circumstances.

With the Inferi, he panicked and was desperately trying every spell he could think of because he forgot that he needed to conjure fire.

In terms of Snape, he had just seen Snape kill Dumbledore. At that point, he was willing to do whatever foul curse came to mind in revenge.

Keep in mind that Harry had also attempted to use the Cruciatus Curse on Bellatrix Lestrange in revenge for killing Sirius (even though doing so could've resulted in a life prison sentence at that point) and on a Amycus Carrow in revenge for spitting in McGonagall's face (which was *technically* legal at that point, but still...) - he didn't do that because he had any great love for the Cruciatus Curse, but rather because he was sufficiently enraged at the person to apply it.

Comment: Also Harry using Sectumsempra gives a dramatic way to reveal Snaps as the HBP... *"You dare use my own spells against me!"*